# How to eliminate malicious code in my wordpress site

Tags: wordpress, security

a while ago my site was hacked and now I find that the site requests this url https://cdn.dokondigit.quest/wp-sentry-browser.min.js, do you know how I could eliminate that request, thanks in advance

I took some security measures, installed a plugin to handle security, changed passwords and put 2FA and some rules in .htaccess, I looked for the code in my files and they don't appear.

Comment: Search DB and files for it (only url parts like "dokondigit" or "wp-sentry"). Furthermore, it could be inserted in any plugin or theme, so deactivate them one by one and look for the request.

Answer (score -2):

You can block the URLs via IPTables;

`sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -d URL_YOU_WANT_TO_BLOCK -j DROP`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).